# What is Deferred Object in Jquery? Kindly give me a meaningfull Example to understand.

Tags: jquery

i was working on a project where i required to "Patient biographic detail e.g Age,Cell number" to show on patient bill,to do this task i made a DB call  to get data ("Age,Cell phone") but before came back response from this DB call another line of code under the DB call(where i called DbCall function)executed and Printed the bill successfully but missing Age,and cell number.
At this scenario i used deferred objects to make sure When my db call give me response then code under the "WHere i called DBCall mathod" execute.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. Your problem description is almost incomprehensible

Comment: Explaining code in words without code is really useless.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about promises. Let's say you have a task and you don't know how long it takes to execute, like fetching data from a web service. So, the result of your task is not available yet, and it maybe be available (or not) in the future, and you want the do something based on the result, using an asynchronous approach.

This is when promises can help, by giving you the ability to handle these kinds of problems.